# Recommend a Good URL rewriting tool for IIS

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, rewrite

Can anyone recommend a good URL rewriting tool for IIS on windows server 2003.

I'm a LAMP head, so not sure what to go for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use [IIS Mod-Rewrite](http://www.micronovae.com/ModRewrite/ModRewrite.html). It's not free but it works like a charm. The syntax is the same as that used by Apache's mod_rewrite which flattens the learning curve somewhat.

I know you said IIS6, but for completeness' sake it's worth mentioning that [IIS7 has native URL](http://www.iis.net/extensions/URLRewrite) rewriting capabilities, although it's not clear whether it uses Apache's syntax.

Comment: Cool. Do you need to do a restart of IIS?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. Every time I've installed it it's been on a box that isn't in production yet so I usually do restart IIS. You can test it on a non-production box, even on XP.

Answer (score 1):

[IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) works well.  **Free.**  Works on IIS6 and 7.

Easy to install and get up running quickly.  Includes a helpfile.  Lots of examples.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ISAPI Rewrite (www.isapirewrite.com) is another great option.  Performs very well and gives you all the flexibility that you need.  A manual install at the site level doesn't require a restart of IIS.